# Application process does not exit after main form is closed - using ApplicationContext

Tags: c#, winforms, process, exit, applicationcontext

I have a windows forms application, after closing the main form the process does not exit.

I use an ApplicationContext because I have a presenter which generates my main form.

`Application.Run(new ApplicationContext(Instance.InitPresentationManager()));`

I have the methods DestroyHandle and OnHandleDestroyed overriden for debugging purposes. 
There I can see that DestroyHandle is called but OnHandleDestroyed not!
This is the reason why my process is still running because the ApplicationContext internally registers to the HandleDestroyed event.

In the DestroyHandle methods the property HandleCreated changes even from true to false.
I did even override WndProc and can see that the message "2" is not received (this one calls WmDestroy in Control class and fires the OnHandleDestroyed event).

How is this possible?

Remarks:

- OnHandleDestroy is only called in the beginning when RecreatingHandle is true
- When attaching to the process and breaking all threads, main thread is still in the Application.Run method
- I did even attach with a memory profiler which tells me that there are no live instances of my main form any more
- Application.Exit in the Dispose of the main form works and deals with the symptoms but does not deal with the problem itself
- After computer restart it works fine for some time but eventually the problems occurs again
- Win 7 64 bit, VS 2010, .net 4.0

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that a form closing, does not necessarily mean the application should terminate what it is currently doing. (think writing log files, closing communications streams neatly etc).

A thread has a property `IsBackground` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground(v=vs.110).aspx) which effectively signifies whether or not it is allowed to be killed in mid operation. Check any ongoing threads to make sure that they are running with the appropriate background thread marker.

Try the dispose method on the application context. This is a perfectly acceptable pattern and way of saying I'm done with this, go and get rid of it, to allow long running threads to finish up.

Comment: By using Application.Run this necessarily means that when the form is closed the application has to exit, see MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157902%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Terminate != exit. Terminate is "Stop what you're doing right now". Exit is "Finish when you're done"

Comment: This is what I mentionend in my question. The main thread is still running. Therefore the application does not exit. Even worse it seems there is a mistake in MSDN documentation, they state Application.Run is waiting for form close event. I checked the source they are waiting for handle destroyed event - which is in my case not firing.

Comment: What processing is going on in your main form? do you start any threads? Can you supply a bare bones source code example?

Comment: The main form is more or less stupid. Just GUI stuff and registering event handlers on buttons and so on. That is the reason for the whole presenter implementation, to keep business logic away from GUI controls and forms.